# In TypeScript, what is the best way to define a function that can return either Promise<T> or Promise<T[]>?

Tags: javascript, typescript, massivejs

I'm just starting with TypeScript and I ran across a situation in which the type definitions for a library I'm using is wrong. In my case, the library is [Massive,js](https://github.com/dmfay/massive-js), and [here are the type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/massive/index.d.ts).

The problem is that some functions should return either `Promise<T[]>` or `Promise<T>`, but the typings say it's always `Promise<T[]>`.

```
  interface Table<T> {
    // other functions omitted for simplicity
    save(data: object): Promise<T[]>;
    insert(data: object): Promise<T[]>;
    update(dataOrCriteria: object, changesMap?: object): Promise<T[]>;
  }
```

**How do I fix the above functions so they would return  either `Promise<T[]>` or `Promise<T>`?**

Comment: How are you using `Table`? Are you importing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple types.

```js
interface Table<T> {
    // other functions omitted for simplicity
    save(data: object): Promise<T | T[]>;
    insert(data: object): Promise<T | T[]>;
    update(dataOrCriteria: object, changesMap?: object): Promise<T | T[]>;
  }
```

Or when using the library just make T an array of items.

Comment: Thanks, but then the intellisense doesn't work. Is this how I call the function then? `user = await (db.user.save(user) as Promise<dbTypes.IUser>)`

Comment: no, you should initialize the T with the proper type when you create a new instance of that class.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. T is IUser in my case.

Comment: usually when you would make a new instance of Table you'd specify the type of T like new Table<dbTypes.IUser>().